# Sonar scan not the scanning project after java version updated from 11 to 17

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarcloud

For my project, sonarClound was not scanning project because of java source version 11.
After I updated java source version to 17 in my feature branch which is not merged to develop (default branch).
Still sonarCloud is not scanning the project. If I do local sonar scan I can see the analysis.

I am using Java, Maven and Github action workflows.

Maven command used in github action workflow.

```
mvn -B -U sonar:sonar -Dsonar.token=${{ secrets.SONARCLOUD_TOKEN }} 
            -Dsonar.host.url=${{ env.sonar_host_url }} 
            -Dsonar.projectKey=${{ env.project_key }} 
            -Dsonar.organization=myorg 
            -Dsonar.java.source=17 
            -Dsonar.verbose=true 
            -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${{env.CHANGE_ID}} 
            -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${{env.BRANCH_NAME}} 
            -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${{env.CHANGE_TARGET}} 
            -Dsonar.pullrequest.provider=GitHub 
            -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml' 
            -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.repository=myorg/myproject 
            -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.endpoint=https://api.github.com 
            -Dsonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*Dto.java
```

[image: sonar local run]

[image: sonarcloud scan]

Note: I have scan the develop branch with java source version 17.